# Couldn’t define the type of children prop component in React project

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this child component:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    hairColor: string;
    hobbies: string[];
}

interface PersonProps {
    person: Person;
}

const SmallPersonListItem = ({ person }: PersonProps) => {
    const { name, age } = person;
    return (
        <p>
            Name: {name}, age: {age}
        </p>
    );
};

export default SmallPersonListItem;
```

and this is my parent component:

```
interface Props<T> {
    items: T[];
    resourceName: string;
    itemComponent: ComponentType<T>;
}

const RegularList = <T extends object>({
    items,
    resourceName,
    itemComponent: ItemComponent,
}: Props<T>) => {
    return (
        <>
            {items.map((item, i) => (
                <ItemComponent key={i} {...({ [resourceName]: item } as T)} />
            ))}
        </>
    );
};

export default RegularList;
```

I use that like this:

```
const RegularListDemo = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <RegularList<Person>
                items={people}
                resourceName={"person"}
                itemComponent={SmallPersonListItem}
            />
            <RegularList<Person>
                items={people}
                resourceName={"person"}
                itemComponent={LargePersonListItem}
            />
        </>
    );
};

export default RegularListDemo;
```

on the **itemComponent** I have this type error:

```
Type '({ person }: PersonProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<Person>'.
  Type '({ person }: PersonProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<Person>'.
    Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Property 'person' is missing in type 'Person' but required in type 'PersonProps'.ts(2322)
types.ts(9, 5): 'person' is declared here.
RegularList.tsx(7, 5): The expected type comes from property 'itemComponent' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props<Person>'
```

I don't know how to fix it.

I tried to fix the problem through changing the RegularList type but I couldn’t solve it. I know here the T generic has conflict with the Person and PersonProps types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript generic type for a React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735453/typescript-generic-type-for-a-react-component)